# swagger ui without swagger auto apidoc json generation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I'd like to use the nice `io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui` interface but I don't want to have my documentation auto generated via annotations in my springboot app (`/v2/api-docs`).

I have my proper `swagger-api.json` api description file under my project resources, how can I tell `swagger-ui` to use it as default ?

I tried to use: `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/swagger-config.json` as swagger properties but it does not use my file.